# Where Are Relocation Entries Stored in Flat Binaries?

Tags: c++, powerpc

Please be attend to the following example. I have a C++ code that I want to compile under `powerpc` and generate the binary code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function(int x);
int myfunction(int x);

int main() 
{
    int x = function(2);
    int y = myfunction(2);

    return x + y;
}

int function(int x)
{
    return x * myfunction(x);
}

int myfunction(int x)
{
    return x;
}
```

I have two function calls: `call function(2)` and `call myfunction(2)`. I compile this C++ code under `powerpc‍‍‍`. So, now I use the `objdump` to get the assembly behind the object file and that is as follows:

```
00000000 <main>:
   0:   94 21 ff e0     stwu    r1,-32(r1)
   4:   7c 08 02 a6     mflr    r0
   8:   93 e1 00 1c     stw r31,28(r1)
   c:   90 01 00 24     stw r0,36(r1)
  10:   7c 3f 0b 78     mr  r31,r1
  14:   38 60 00 02     li  r3,2
  18:   48 00 00 01     bl  18 <main+0x18>
  1c:   7c 60 1b 78     mr  r0,r3
  20:   90 1f 00 08     stw r0,8(r31)
  24:   38 60 00 02     li  r3,2
  28:   48 00 00 01     bl  28 <main+0x28>
  2c:   7c 60 1b 78     mr  r0,r3
  30:   90 1f 00 0c     stw r0,12(r31)
  34:   80 1f 00 08     lwz r0,8(r31)
  38:   81 3f 00 0c     lwz r9,12(r31)
  3c:   7c 00 4a 14     add r0,r0,r9
  40:   7c 03 03 78     mr  r3,r0
  44:   48 00 00 0c     b   50 <main+0x50>
  48:   38 60 00 00     li  r3,0
  4c:   48 00 00 04     b   50 <main+0x50>
  50:   81 61 00 00     lwz r11,0(r1)
  54:   80 0b 00 04     lwz r0,4(r11)
  58:   7c 08 03 a6     mtlr    r0
  5c:   83 eb ff fc     lwz r31,-4(r11)
  60:   7d 61 5b 78     mr  r1,r11
  64:   4e 80 00 20     blr

00000068 <function__Fi>:
  68:   94 21 ff e0     stwu    r1,-32(r1)
  6c:   7c 08 02 a6     mflr    r0
  70:   93 e1 00 1c     stw r31,28(r1)
  74:   90 01 00 24     stw r0,36(r1)
  78:   7c 3f 0b 78     mr  r31,r1
  7c:   90 7f 00 08     stw r3,8(r31)
  80:   80 7f 00 08     lwz r3,8(r31)
  84:   48 00 00 01     bl  84 <function__Fi+0x1c>
  88:   7c 60 1b 78     mr  r0,r3
  8c:   81 3f 00 08     lwz r9,8(r31)
  90:   7c 00 49 d6     mullw   r0,r0,r9
  94:   7c 03 03 78     mr  r3,r0
  98:   48 00 00 0c     b   a4 <function__Fi+0x3c>
  9c:   48 00 00 08     b   a4 <function__Fi+0x3c>
  a0:   48 00 00 04     b   a4 <function__Fi+0x3c>
  a4:   81 61 00 00     lwz r11,0(r1)
  a8:   80 0b 00 04     lwz r0,4(r11)
  ac:   7c 08 03 a6     mtlr    r0
  b0:   83 eb ff fc     lwz r31,-4(r11)
  b4:   7d 61 5b 78     mr  r1,r11
  b8:   4e 80 00 20     blr

000000bc <myfunction__Fi>:
  bc:   94 21 ff e0     stwu    r1,-32(r1)
  c0:   93 e1 00 1c     stw r31,28(r1)
  c4:   7c 3f 0b 78     mr  r31,r1
  c8:   90 7f 00 08     stw r3,8(r31)
  cc:   80 1f 00 08     lwz r0,8(r31)
  d0:   7c 03 03 78     mr  r3,r0
  d4:   48 00 00 04     b   d8 <myfunction__Fi+0x1c>
  d8:   81 61 00 00     lwz r11,0(r1)
  dc:   83 eb ff fc     lwz r31,-4(r11)
  e0:   7d 61 5b 78     mr  r1,r11
  e4:   4e 80 00 20     blr
```

The interesting thing that wondered me is the line that do function calls:

```
  18:   48 00 00 01     bl  18 <main+0x18>
  ...
  28:   48 00 00 01     bl  28 <main+0x28>
```

As you see, both are the binary code "48 00 00 01", but one calls `function` and another calls `myfunction`. The problem is that how we can find the `call target`. As I found, the call targets are written on `RELOCATION ENTRIES`. Oh, everything is okay, I use the command below to generate the relocation entries and is as follows:

```
RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET   TYPE              VALUE 
00000018 R_PPC_REL24       function__Fi
00000028 R_PPC_REL24       myfunction__Fi
00000084 R_PPC_REL24       myfunction__Fi
```

This entries are useful to find the call target. Now, I use the `objcopy -O binary` command to generate the raw binary file (flat binary).

```
objcopy -O binary object-file
```

My `object-file` is the `elf32-powerpc`. The output binary file shown in following block:

```
2564 0000 2564 0a00 93e1 001c 9001 0024
7c3f 0b78 3860 0002 4800 0001 7c60 1b78
901f 0008 3860 0002 4800 0001 7c60 1b78
901f 000c 801f 0008 2c00 0002 4182 003c
2c00 0002 4181 0010 2c00 0001 4182 0014
4800 0058 2c00 0003 4182 0038 4800 004c
3d20 0000 3869 0000 389f 0008 4cc6 3182
4800 0001 4800 004c 3d20 0000 3869 0004
3880 0014 4cc6 3182 4800 0001 4800 0034
3d20 0000 3869 0004 3880 001e 4cc6 3182
4800 0001 4800 001c 3d20 0000 3869 0004
3880 0028 4cc6 3182 4800 0001 4800 0004
3860 0000 4800 0004 8161 0000 800b 0004
7c08 03a6 83eb fffc 7d61 5b78 4e80 0020
9421 ffe0 7c08 02a6 93e1 001c 9001 0024
7c3f 0b78 907f 0008 807f 0008 4800 0001
7c60 1b78 813f 0008 7c00 49d6 7c03 0378
4800 000c 4800 0008 4800 0004 8161 0000
800b 0004 7c08 03a6 83eb fffc 7d61 5b78
4e80 0020 9421 ffe0 93e1 001c 7c3f 0b78
907f 0008 801f 0008 7c03 0378 4800 0004
8161 0000 83eb fffc 7d61 5b78 4e80 0020
```

We can find the `4800 0001` on it. But there is no `relocation entries`. Could any one please tell me how can I find the `relocation entries`?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can't, `objcopy`ing to binary will strip them out.

Comment: So, how is this useful?

Answer (score 1):

Your relocation entries are discarded when you do the objcopy. From the manual:

> objcopy can be used to generate a raw binary file by using an output
>   target of binary (e.g., use -O binary).  When objcopy generates a raw
>   binary file, it will essentially produce a memory dump of the contents
>   of the input object file.  **All symbols and relocation information will
>   be discarded.**  The memory dump will start at the load address of the
>   lowest section copied into the output file.

For your raw binary to be useful, you have a few options here:

You can perform the relocations during the build process, so that your raw binary is ready to run. However, this means that the binary file needs to be run at a fixed address in memory.

Alternatively, you can produce an object file that does not require relocation - all address references need to be relative. Lookup "position-independent code" for more details.

Finally, you could also use some other way of generating the raw binary (instead of, or in addition to, the `objcopy` stage), which includes the relocation table in the output file, and then have your code manually process these relocations at runtime.

The choice here will depend on what you're trying to do, and what constraints your runtime environment has.